# Python sqlite3 execute with both named and qmark parameters

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to execute an SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE spam LIKE ? AND eggs LIKE :eggs
```

Python sqlite3 module documentation says:

> Cursor.execute(sql[, parameters])
>
> [...]
>
> The sqlite3 module supports two kinds of placeholders: question marks (qmark style) and named placeholders (named style).

But is there a way to use both qmark style and named style?

SOLUTION (thanks to jadkik94):

```
params = ["a","b","c"]
kparams = {'d':"d", 'e':"e"}
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (a LIKE ? OR b LIKE ? OR c LIKE ?) AND (d LIKE :d AND e LIKE :e)"
sql = sql.replace("?", ":{}").format(*range(sql.count("?")))
# >>> sql
# "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (a like :0 OR b like :1 OR c like :2) AND (d like :d AND e like :e)"
kparams.update(dict(map(lambda x: (str(x[0]), x[1]), enumerate(params))))
# >>> kparams
# {'0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2': 'c', 'd': 'd', 'e': 'e'}
c.execute(sql, kparams)
```

Comment: why would you need this? i never saw that anyway. but you could make your own function to do this...

Comment: My statement looks like this: SELECT * FROM table WHERE (a like ? OR b like ? OR c like ?) AND (d like :d AND e like :e)  A B and C are generated automatically in my script, so they don't have unique names, but D and E do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is your code:

```
known = {'d': 'dval', 'e': 'eval'}
unknown = ['a', 'b', 'c']
# instead of
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE (a like ? OR b like ? OR c like ?) AND (d like :d AND e like :e)"
known.update(dict((str(i), v) for i, v in enumerate(unknown)))
# and use
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE (a like :1 OR b like :2 OR c like :3) AND (d like :d AND e like :e)"
```

I guess you cannot use both ways together, but that's one alternative.

Comment: That's a good idea. But I still think it should be implemented in the sqlite3 module.

Comment: Yes and you could do `execute(sql, dict, list)`, but I never saw this anywhere else ... maybe there's a reason for that

Comment: The keys of the dict need to be strings. So you need this: `known.update(dict(map(lambda x: (str(x[0]), x[1]), enumerate(unknown)))`

Comment: Yes, but it's not that `dict`s don't accept integers as keys, it's just that `Cursor.commit` expects them to be strings, but you're right, I'll update the answer :)