# python sqlite3 .executemany() with named placeholders?

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

This works:

```
ss = 'insert into images (file_path) values(?);'
dddd = (('dd1',), ('dd2',))
conn.executemany(ss, dddd)
```

However this does not:

```
s = 'insert into images (file_path) values (:v)'
ddddd = ({':v': 'dd11'}, {':v': 'dd22'})
conn.executemany(s, ddddd)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Wes/.virtualenvs/ppyy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-31-a999de59f73b>", line 1, in <module>
    conn.executemany(s, ddddd)
ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 1.
```

I am wondering if it is possible to use named parameters with executemany and, if so, how.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects) at section 11.13.3 talks generally about parameters but doesn't discuss the two styles of parameters that are described for other flavors of  .executexxx().

I have checked out [Python sqlite3 execute with both named and qmark parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246542/python-sqlite3-execute-with-both-named-and-qmark-parameters) which does not pertain to executemany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [source](https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/blob/master/src/cursor.c) shows that `execute()` simply constructs a one-element list and calls `executemany()`, so the problem is not with `executemany()` itself; the same call fails with `execute()`:

```
>>> conn.execute('SELECT :v', {':v': 42})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 1.
```

As shown in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute), named parameters do not include the colon:

> ```
> # And this is the named style:
> cur.execute("select * from people where name_last=:who and age=:age", {"who": who, "age": age})
> ```

So you have to use `ddddd = ({'v': 'dd11'}, {'v': 'dd22'})`.

Answer (score 2):

The `:` isn't part of the parameter name.

```
>>> s = 'insert into images (file_path) values (:v)'
>>> ddddd = ({'v': 'dd11'}, {'v': 'dd22'})
>>> conn.executemany(s, ddddd)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000000002C0E500>
>>> conn.execute('select * from images').fetchall()
[(u'dd11',), (u'dd22',)]
```

Comment: I am sorry that I can't give both of you checkmarks.